# Trying to connect to tor with python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, tor

I have been trying to connect to tor with python on Mac. If it helps, I have python3 and Mac Mojave. My code is:

```
import stem.process
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from splinter import Browser

proxyIP = "127.0.0.1"
proxyPort = 9150

proxy_settings = {"network.proxy.type":1,
    "network.proxy.ssl": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.ssl_port": proxyPort,
    "network.proxy.socks": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.socks_port": proxyPort,
    "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns": True,
    "network.proxy.ftp": proxyIP,
    "network.proxy.ftp_port": proxyPort
}
browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)
browser.visit("http://www.icanhazip.com")
```

However, whenever I run it, an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    browser = Browser('firefox', profile_preferences=proxy_settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 64, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 78, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Any help would be appreciated. Regards, Tyler

Comment: it is your geckodriver version causing that, what is your selenuim version and geckodriver version

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your selenium version and geckodriver version,so what i can answer is `upgrade them`.

> pip install -U selenium
>
> download latest version geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)